# Seller ID is mandatory for parallel payments

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I want to create a marketplace where users can list items and have buyers pay them directly through paypal.

my code as:

```
$config =  $config = vn3dUtil::getPaypalConfig();
            $paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService($config);
            $setECReqDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();


            $cart=$this->ZendCart()->cart();
            //for
            $k=0;
            foreach ($cart as $key => $po) {

            $itemDetails = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
            $itemDetails->Name = $po['name'];
            $itemAmount =  $po['price'];
            $itemDetails->Amount = $itemAmount;
//             $itemQuantity = $po['qty'];
            $itemQuantity = '1';
            $itemDetails->Quantity = $itemQuantity;

             //add one product
            $paymentDetails= new PaymentDetailsType();

            $paymentDetails->PaymentDetailsItem[$k] = $itemDetails;

            //set total
            $orderTotal = new BasicAmountType();
            $orderTotal->currencyID = 'USD';

            $orderTotal->value = $itemAmount * $itemQuantity;
            $paymentDetails->OrderTotal = $orderTotal;



            $paymentDetails->PaymentAction = 'Sale';
            $setECReqDetails->PaymentDetails[$k] = $paymentDetails;

            //end for
            $k++;
            }



            //
            $setECReqDetails->CancelURL = vn3dUtil::DOMAIN;
            $setECReqDetails->ReturnURL = vn3dUtil::DOMAIN."/store/checkout-detail";

            $setECReqType = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
            $setECReqType->Version = '104.0';
            $setECReqType->SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = $setECReqDetails;

            $setECReq = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
            $setECReq->SetExpressCheckoutRequest = $setECReqType;

//             var_dump($setECReq);

            $setECResponse = $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq);
            var_dump($setECResponse->Token);
            var_dump($setECResponse);
            if($setECResponse->Ack=="Success"){
             $this->redirect()->toUrl("https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=".$setECResponse->Token);
            }
```

Paypal is respond "seller ID is mandatory for parallel payments."

would you suggest to do this?

```
object(SetExpressCheckoutResponseType)[259]
      public 'Token' => null
      public 'Timestamp' => string '2014-02-15T20:47:42Z' (length=20)
      public 'Ack' => string 'Failure' (length=7)
      public 'CorrelationID' => string '412c6c6aa36c1' (length=13)
      public 'Errors' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            object(ErrorType)[268]
              public 'ShortMessage' => string 'Seller ID Missing.' (length=18)
              public 'LongMessage' => string 'Seller ID is mandatory for parallel payments.' (length=45)
              public 'ErrorCode' => string '13115' (length=5)
              public 'SeverityCode' => string 'Error' (length=5)
              public 'ErrorParameters' => null
      public 'Version' => string '104.0' (length=5)
      public 'Build' => string '9720069' (length=7)
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck fixing up the request code which you didn't show us, preventing us from being able to help you at all.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned, we need to see the actual request.  In what you've shown, though, I don't see anything specific to $Receivers..??  Where are you setting up the receivers on the payment?  If that's missing then that's probably why you're getting this error.